# Your financial institution has indicated that it could not successfully authenticate this transaction.

Tags: paypal

I'm getting this intermittent message on checkout in BigCommerce.

Your financial institution has indicated that it could not successfully authenticate this transaction. To protect against unauthorized use, this card cannot be used to complete your purchase. You may complete the purchase by selecting another form of payment or use a different card.

My API is correct with Paypal Payments Pro, Check out works and then doesn't work.  Tried a few cards, sometimes the card worked, and sometimes it didn't.  Here is the error message.

Your financial institution has indicated that it could not successfully authenticate this transaction. To protect against unauthorized use, this card cannot be used to complete your purchase. You may complete the purchase by selecting another form of payment or use a different card.

I have the same account setup on another BigCommerce site and never had a problem.

Comment: Give an appropriate title to the question. You have already mentioned the message again in the question body. Try to highlight the message using code block if you want users to pay attention to it.

Comment: What is the actual API response that you get back from your PayPal Payments Pro API call.  There should be a short message, a long message, and error code that gets returned.  The error you provided, seems like an error from the cart and could be a bit cryptic.  You need to look at the API response that is getting returned, or provide the API response that gets returned and I can check into it from my side.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another BigCommerce site and are using the PayPal account, make sure that your starting invoice numbers are far enough apart, otherwise you will be sending duplicate invoice numbers to PayPal and end they'll return an error. I was getting the same error, and I just set had to set one of my store's starting invoice number (under store settings/misc) to a really high number. This fixed the problem. Thanks BigCommerce tech support guy!

(You should be able to see what error you are getting by going through your store logs)